# Retain indexes from a dataframe based on indexes of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have two dataframes `A` and `B` indexed from `0` to `10`. I remove a couple of duplicate rows from A so that the indexes `7` and `9` are removed. So now `A.index` will be `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10]`.

Now I want to retain exactly the rows having these same indexes in `B`. As of now its index set is from `0` to `10`. In other words, given the exact same index initially, and having dropped a few indexes from `A`, how do I retain the subset of `B` rows that exactly correspond to retained rows of `A` in terms of their index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can select by `loc`:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'col':[5,8,4,0,6,2,1,8,3,4,9]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.arange(10, 21)})
#print (A)
#print (B)

A1 = A.drop_duplicates('col')
print (A1)
    col
0     5
1     8
2     4
3     0
4     6
5     2
6     1
8     3
10    9

B1  = B.loc[A1.index]
print (B1)
    col
0    10
1    11
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
6    16
8    18
10   20
```